# How to find Hamiltonian for $\mathcal{L}_2=-{1\over16\pi c} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+{1\over2\chi}\partial_\mu A\partial^\mu A$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism

1. How to find Hamiltonian for $$\mathcal{L}_2=-{1\over16\pi c}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+{1\over2\chi}\partial_\mu A\partial^\mu A~?$$
2. What happens when $\chi\rightarrow+0$?

I can find Hamiltonian for  $\mathcal{L}_1=-{1\over16\pi c} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$   when $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$.

Comment: Where is the index on $A$ in the title?

Comment: apparently this error in the exercise, let's put the index

Comment: Be specific. There are several possibilities.